# Angular Material (Flat-Tree) to display nested objects in tree structure and enable serach

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

I have the requirement to display the the following nested objects to display in tree stricture and able to search.(similar to below example)
[image]

I searched many examples to achieve this (there are example for the simple tree structure could not find one with multiple nested objects).

I have tried the following but its not working(I have tried nested tree did not work) ,can anyone please help if you came across the scenario.

> List of Interfaces

```
 export interface EXAMPLE1{ 
  aname:string;
  example2:EXAMPLE2[]  
}

export interface EXAMPLE2{ 
  aname?:string; 
  example3:EXAMPLE3[]
}

export interface EXAMPLE3{  
  aname:string;  
  example4:EXAMPLE4[]
}
    
export interface EXAMPLE4{
  aname:string; 
}
```

> tree-view.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput minlength="2" (keyup)="applyFilter(input.value)" placeholder="Filter" #input>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

> tree-view.component.ts

```
export interface EXAMPLE1{ 
  aname:string;
  example2:EXAMPLE2[]  
}

export interface EXAMPLE2{ 
  aname?:string; 
  example3:EXAMPLE3[]
}

export interface EXAMPLE3{  
  aname:string;  
  example4:EXAMPLE4[]
}


export interface EXAMPLE4{
  aname:string; 
}


const TREE_DATA1: SOModel[] = [
    EXAMPLE1:[
        {
          aname:"example1-Name",
          example2:[
                {
                    aname:"example2-Name",
                    example3: [
                         {
                           aname:"example3-Name",
                           example4:[
                               {
                                   aname:"example4-Name"

                               }
                           ]
                         }
                    ]
                }          
          ]
        }
    ];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.scss']
})
export class TreeViewComponent {

 // private _transformer = (node: FoodNode, level: number) => {
    private _transformer = (node: SOModel, level: number) => {
    return {
      expandable: !!node.example2 && node.example2.length > 0,
      name: node.aname,
      level: level
    };
  };

  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeFlatNode>(
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable
  );


  treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
    this._transformer,
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
    node => node.example2
  );

  dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: TreeFlatNode) => node.expandable;


  // filter recursively on a text string using property object value
  filterRecursive(filterText: string, array: any[], property: string) {
    let filteredData;

    //make a copy of the data so we don't mutate the original
    function copy(o: any) {
      return Object.assign({}, o);
    }

    // has string
    if (filterText) {
      // need the string to match the property value
      filterText = filterText.toLowerCase();
      // copy obj so we don't mutate it and filter
      filteredData = array.map(copy).filter(function x(y) {
        if (y[property].toLowerCase().includes(filterText)) {
          return true;
        }
        // if children match
        if (y.children) {
          return (y.children = y.children.map(copy).filter(x)).length;
        }
      });
      // no string, return whole array
    } else {
      filteredData = array;
    }

    return filteredData;
  }

  // pass mat input string to recursive function and return data
  filterTree(filterText: string) {
    // use filter input text, return filtered TREE_DATA, use the 'name' object value
    this.dataSource.data = this.filterRecursive(filterText, TREE_DATA, 'name');
  }

  // filter string from mat input filter
  applyFilter(filterText: string) {
    this.filterTree(filterText);
    // show / hide based on state of filter string
    if (filterText) {
      this.treeControl.expandAll();
    } else {
      this.treeControl.collapseAll();
    }
  }



  

}
```